# Call php script from python

Tags: php, python, subprocess, execution

Is there a way to exec php script in python? And how to test it? Because I have try using subprocess, but it doesn't work. The output is 255

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["php","-f","01_getdata_input.php","bib_id_skjawasur_texts","bib_id_ayt_texts"])
```

My php file like this

```
<?php
require_once "libs/c_db.php";
require "libs/c_general.php";

$obj = new ProsesData();
$obj->proses($argv[0],$argv[1]);

class ProsesData
{
  private $table;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new c_DB("localhost", "root", "", "skripsi");
    $this->libs = new c_General();
  }

  public function proses($data1,$data2) {
    echo $data1;
  }
};
```

Comment: If you have the PHP file inside a webserver you could make a request to it using Requests library.

Comment: You should to make a minimal reproduction case.

Create a simple PHP file with an echo inside it and test what happens.